# Android TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile() file is not created

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, text-to-speech

I am trying to implement a pause and play function to some text using tts and MediaPlayer. However, I can't seem to be able to create a .wav file using the synthesizeToFile function.

I already added the required permission to the xml file:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is the file creation method I am currently using:

```
private String envPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + "/Download";
private Uri fileUri;

public void fileCreate() {
    String inputText = output.getText().toString();

    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, inputText);
    Log.d(TAG, "successfully created hashmap");

    String destFileName = envPath + "/" + "tts_file.wav";

    int sr = tts.synthesizeToFile(inputText, myHashRender, destFileName);
    Log.d(TAG, "synthesize returns = " + sr);
    File fileTTS = new File(destFileName);

    if (fileTTS.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "successfully created fileTTS");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "failed while creating fileTTS");
    }

    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(fileTTS);
    Log.d(TAG, "successfully created uri link: " + fileUri.getPath());
}
```

This is how I create the mediaPlayer:

```
fileCreate();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, fileUri);
    Log.d(TAG, "successfuly created mediaplayer");

    btnRead.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.pause();
                Log.d(TAG, "successfully paused");
            } else {
                mp.start();
                Log.d(TAG, "successfully started");
            }
        }

    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `synthesizeToFile` is asynchronous thus you should do the checking

```
File fileTTS = new File(destFileName);

if (fileTTS.exists()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "successfully created fileTTS");
}
else {
    Log.d(TAG, "failed while creating fileTTS");
}
```

in `onUtteranceCompletedListener` or `UtteranceProgressListener`

Comment: Thank you! I used the guide found here: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-text-to-speech-implementing-pause-and-resume-in-tts-using-mediaplayer/