# Saving Bigger Files with TTS Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Recently i used android TTS - I save the file as MP3 and play it using MediaPlayer so users can pause/resume etc.

It all works fine other than when i have a large text it just does not work.

I read that the android TTS has the limit of 4000 CHs? What should i do to tackle large amount of text?

The following is the code i am using to save MP3

```
Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
...
textToSpeech = new Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech(this, this, "com.google.android.tts");
...
textToSpeech.SynthesizeToFile(ReadableText, null, new Java.IO.File(System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, ID + "_audio.mp3")), ID);
```

The following is the code i am using to playback the audio

```
MediaPlayer MP = new MediaPlayer();
...
MP.SetDataSource(System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, ID + "_audio.mp3"));
MP.Prepare();
MP.Start();
```

It works for small amount of text but not for large text.

File gets saved (most likely just a corrupt file) because when i play it i get the following error

```
setDataSoruceFD failed: status=0x80000000
```

> Java Solution is also acceptable

FYI - The question is about the max text size as I can generate the file for smaller text

Cheers

Comment: Looks like it is async, does that make a difference in my case though?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile() file is not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714989/android-texttospeech-synthesizetofile-file-is-not-created)

Comment: Tested again, yes it is getting enough time to process the text, I play after the file is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android ASOP (at least since API-18), `TextToSpeech.MaxSpeechInputLength` is set to `4000`.

Note: OEMs could change this value in their OS image, so it would be wise to check the value and not make any assumptions.

Note: You are naming the output with an `.mp3` extension, but by default the files created will be `.wav` formatted, some speech engines do support other formats/bitrate/etc. but you are passing null for the parameters.

Unless you want to deal with properly joining multiple wave files, I would recommend that you break your text into smaller parts and synthesize multiple files.

You can then play these back in sequence (using the MediaPlayer Completion event|listener).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, you are right, I will have to split text into smaller files, in regards to passing type as null and saving wav as MP3,  can you please elaborate what you mean? Also love the idea idea of checking the value as you said OEMs can change the value but given that 4000 is the minimum, for consistency, what do you think if I just stick with one size over all the devices.

Comment: @aliusman `stick with one size over all the devices` You very well might be fine, *or not ;-)* `MaxSpeechInputLength` was added in API-18 to allow the developer a means to check the max. length available, ***personally*** I would use it on API18+ and assume 4000 for lower APIs, but in the end, the choice is yours...

Comment: Thank you, would like to shed some light on `Note: You are naming the output with an .mp3 extension, but by default the files created will be .wav formatted, some speech engines do support other formats/bitrate/etc. but you are passing null for the parameters.` please

Comment: @aliusman The various TTS engines support different parameters, some you can pass in params for the generated voice type, pitch, speed, format, etc.. that will be generated. These are TTS engine dependent and so there is not a master list of them in some Google Android document, you have to look at the engine itself to determine what additional features are supported (if anything). Mostly you use the  HashMap (or Bundle in the API-21+ version of SynthesizeToFile) to set an utterance id for the async callback listener to know when the file is done being created.