# How to convert text to speech to audio file and play it

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

My goal is to convert text to speech to a audio file and play it. I am getting

> java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.

I am new to android. Please help.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "speak");

File myDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
String documents = "documents/data";
File documentsFolder = new File(myDir, documents);
documentsFolder.mkdir();

String path = "/"+documents+"/"+"test.mp3";

textToSpeech.synthesizeToFile("text to speech to audio", map, path);
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try{
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("ROYs", e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

**Update #1**

```
File folder = getFilesDir();
File f= new File(folder, "doc_download");
f.mkdir();
```

There are a few questions on stack overflow that are similar to my question. But the answer did not solve my problem.

Comment: That seems like the resource located at "path" isn't there when you call '.setDataSource(path)'. Have you tried removing the leading "/" when you create the path variable?

Comment: I have done it now. But same error.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? If so put a break point on the line after you declare the path variable, and then use the device explorer to check to see if the file exists and if the file path is correct.

Comment: I've checked internal storage of my phone. It seems that the documents directory is not exist. Is there any way to check it programmatically?

Comment: file.exists() I believe is what the command would be.

Comment: I was unable to create the directory with my code.

Comment: I've checked it by file.exists() method. But Update #1 section have created the directory successfully. Now what will be the directory path?. My package is  com.troy.texttospeech

Comment: maybe path is not correct that's why synthesizeToFile() returning -1

Comment: What are you doing to support the asynchronous nature of synthesizeToFile()?

Comment: You need decoding file before it will work

You can use this documentation
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/base64-decoding

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what's happening is that `textToSpeech.synthesizeToFile("text to speech to audio", map, path);` isn't creating the file that you think it is, **or** it's not creating it where you think it's suppose to be creating it.

Please see this SO question ([Android TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile() file is not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714989/android-texttospeech-synthesizetofile-file-is-not-created))